# Simple way to read nested dictionary without iterating

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
nest_dict = {
    "1": {
        "Name": X,
        "Class": "10",
        "Roll_no": 19289,
        "Marks": 126
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": Y,
        "Class": "12",
        "Roll_no": 19290,
        "Marks": 124
    }
}.
```

Please note that each sub-entry has the same set of keys, i.e. Name, Class, Roll_no, Marks. How do I get list of `all_Names = [X, Y]`, `all_Class = [10, 12]`, `all_Roll_no = [19289, 19290]`, `all_Marks = [126, 124]` without having to iterate over the entries in the preceding level, i.e. 1,2. There should be some simple way to achieve this, right? (I am trying to parse from a json file using python3.)

Comment: Please add tags for the language and any other components you are using to consume this JSON to help your question be seen by the users best able to answer it.

Comment: What do you mean by "without iterating"? How do you imagine this solution will look?

Comment: _Why_ does it have to be without iteration? You _could_ hardcode all the keys and access each sub-dict by their respective keys .... but that's really bad code and you would need to know all the keys in advance. The simple way would actually be iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`all_Names = [y['Name'] for x,y in nest_dict.items()]`
and so on for others 'Class', 'Roll_no', ... should be simple enough.

Comment: otherwise
 `all_Names = [v['Name'] for v in nest_dict.values()]`, 

`all_Classes = [v['Class'] for v in nest_dict.values()]`

and so forth

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate. The code is simple enough, fast and efficient. I don't see many other ways around it.

Example:

```
nest_dict = {
    "1": {
        "Name": "X",
        "Class": "10",
        "Roll_no": 19289,
        "Marks": 126
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": "Y",
        "Class": "12",
        "Roll_no": 19290,
        "Marks": 124
    }
}


all_roll_numbers = set()
all_names = set()
all_classes = set()
all_marks = set()

for data in nest_dict.values():
    all_names.add(data["Name"])
    all_classes.add(data["Class"])
    all_roll_numbers.add(data["Roll_no"])
    all_marks.add(data["Marks"])
```

A different take:

```
data = {
    "Name": set(),
    "Class": set(),
    "Roll_no": set(),
    "Marks": set()
}

for item in nest_dict.values():
    for key, value in item.items():
        data[key].add(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

> There should be some simple way to achieve this, right?

is this simple enough?:

```
import pandas as pd

nest_dict = {
    "1": {
        "Name": 'X',
        "Class": "10",
        "Roll_no": 19289,
        "Marks": 126
    },
    "2": {
        "Name": 'Y',
        "Class": "12",
        "Roll_no": 19290,
        "Marks": 124
    }}

res = pd.DataFrame(nest_dict.values()).T.apply(list,1).to_dict()

>>> res
'''
{'Name': ['X', 'Y'],
 'Class': ['10', '12'],
 'Roll_no': [19289, 19290],
 'Marks': [126, 124]}
```

Comment: Thank you.. but I already had a simpler workaround.